# Update/evaluate/render a server-side output from UI (for use as conditionalPanel's condition) without displaying it

Tags: r, shiny

I have a conditionalPanel in my UI that needs to check whether a certain calculation was possible, and if so, display the output, or if not, display an explanation.

Here's a simplified example:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    textOutput("ispossible"),
    conditionalPanel('output.ispossible === "FALSE"',
                     h4('The calculation is NOT possible')),
    conditionalPanel('output.ispossible === "TRUE"',
                     h4('The calculation IS possible'))
  ), 
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$ispossible <- reactive({
      sample(c("TRUE","FALSE"),1)     # randomly returns "TRUE" or "FALSE"
    })
  }
)
```

In this code, if you change `return("FALSE")` to `return("TRUE")`, the conditionalPanel changes as appropriate. **However**, this is only because the `textOutput` rendered the output first. Remove the `textOutput` and it doesn't work. How can I force `output$ispossible` to update without displaying it -- or how can I hide the output?

Comment: It would seem like a good option to use `values$ispossible` instead, but it doesn't work: conditionalPanel evaluates no matter what `values$ispossible` is.

Comment: Hmmm, a workaround is to have `output$ispossible` return either one space or two spaces instead of TRUE or FALSE, and render it at the bottom of the page.